# How to cope with the error of the following piece of system verilog code?

Tags: system-verilog

schematic
[image: schematic]

I would like to write system verilog code to implement this schematic (using 3 2:4 decoder and 64 3-input and gate to achieve a 6:64 decoder), and the following is my piece of code:

```
module Ex4( input logic [5:0] D,
            output logic [63:0] y
         );

    genvar i;
    genvar j;
    genvar k;
    integer n = 0;
    logic [3:0] y1, y2, y3;

    dec2 d1(D[1:0], y1);
    dec2 d2(D[3:2], y2);
    dec2 d3(D[5:4], y3);

    generate
      begin 
        for(i = 0; i < 3; i = i + 1) begin:flp1
            for (j = 0; j < 3; j = j + 1) begin:flp2
                for(k = 0; k < 3; k = k + 1) begin:flp3
                   and3_new a_n(y1[i], y2[j], y3[k], y[n]);
                   n=n+1; // error message comes from this line
                end
            end
        end
     end
   endgenerate  
endmodule
```

Note: `"dec2"` and `"and3_new"` are two modules written in advance with no problems

However, I got the following error during compilation, can anybody give me some hint? Thank you.

> Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at Ex4.sv(22) near text: "=";
>   expecting ".", or "(". Check for and fix any syntax errors that appear
>   immediately before or at the specified keyword. The Intel FPGA
>   Knowledge  Database contains many articles with specific details on
>   how to resolve  this error. Visit the Knowledge Database at 
>   https://www.altera.com/support/support-resources/knowledge-
>   base/search.html and search for this specific error message number.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put a procedural assignment statement in that position. Instead of `[n]`, use `[i*16+j*4+k]`. You can also do

```
module Ex4( input logic [5:0] D,
            output logic [63:0] y
         );
    logic [3:0] y1, y2, y3;

    dec2 d1(D[1:0], y1);
    dec2 d2(D[3:2], y2);
    dec2 d3(D[5:4], y3);

        for(genvar i = 0; i < 4; i++) begin:flp1
            for (genvar j = 0; j < 4; j++) begin:flp2
                for(genvar k = 0; k < 4; k = k + 1) begin:flp3
                   parameter n = i*16+j*4+k;
                   and3_new a_n(y1[i], y2[j], y3[k], y[n]);
                end :flp3
            end : flp2
        end : flp1

endmodule
```